# extra trailing closure passed in call

Tags: swift, xcode

can some one please help with this code. I am receiving an error "Extra trailing closure passed in call" I have created a list of names, however, I wanted to show photos on the individual on the list instead of the name. However, when I tried this I am receiving an error. Can someone pease help me fix this, or can anyone help me how to create a list with photos of each individual with their names?
Will I be able to create a list with names and image uploaded from users photo library?

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import PhotosUI

struct Task : Identifiable {
    var id = String()
    var toDoItem = String()
}

class TaskStore : ObservableObject {
    @Published var tasks = [Task]()
}

@MainActor
class ImageModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published  var image: Image?
    
    @Published var imageSelection: PhotosPickerItem? {
        didSet {
            if let imageSelection {
                Task { // --> ERROR in THIS LINE "extra trailing closure passed in call"
                    try await loadTransferable(from: imageSelection)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func loadTransferable(from imageSelection: PhotosPickerItem?) async throws  {
        do {
            if let data = try await imageSelection?.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) {
                if let uiImage = UIImage(data: data) {
                    print("success")
                    self.image = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            fatalError("Image issue")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Daniel I think it's showing an error because I am using multiple Tasks. Not sure why . try? await loadTransferable(from: imageSelection) did not help.

Comment: rename your `struct Task` to something else, eg `struct MyTask`. Swift has already a `Task`. You are confusing yourself and the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `Task` struct is conflicting with Swift's `Task`. Your attempted use of `Task` is being interpreted as a use of your `Task` struct.

You have two solutions:

1. Rename your `Task` struct to some other name to avoid the naming collision.
2. Prefix the use of Swift's `Task` with its module name:

   ```swift
   SwiftUI.Task {
       try await loadTransferable(from: imageSelection)
   }
   ```